# How to write a program that you give it 3 grades to a student in a class and it returns the average of all three

Tags: c#, average

Average grades for student 1 = 85.56

Average grades for student 2 = 88.20

Average grades for student 3 = 98.00

.
.
.

Average grades for student 30 = 97.25

Attempt:

public static double average(int a, int b, int c)

double avrg;

avrg = (a+b+c)/3;

Comment: Please, show your attempts.

Comment: Hello, can you provide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ?
We are not here to do your homework, we are here to help you solving any issues you might run into.

Comment: You can do this by writing code. What issue are you facing in that?

Comment: I don't know how to write it.

Comment: `return (a+b+c)/3.0;`

Comment: If you don't know how to write it, you will almost certainly get far more benefit from running through some tutorials than asking here for us to do your work for you.

Comment: You should start reading and learning the stuff instead of looking for ready made solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question is not clear at all, I think you search something like:

```
public double getAverage(double grade1, double grade2, double grade3) {
    return (grade1 + grade2 + grade3)/3;
}
```

Comment: Why those `public double grade{number};`?

Comment: @Rafalon His question is actually not clear at all, I just try to give him some information that he can develop further.

Comment: I'm just saying that your 3 first code lines seem quite useless here. (I don't know if that's why you got that downvote though)

Comment: @Rafalon in this context you're probably right. corrected that

Comment: If OPs question is not clear, why have you answered it at all?